# How to override web api route on the same method with annotations

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have this configuration in the HttpConfiguration

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("Default", "api/{controller}");
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("Another", "api/{controller}/{action}");
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("WithKey", "api/{controller}/{action}/{key}");
```

For that reason I cannot access my controller like this

```
http://<host>/api/products (works)
http://<host>/api/products/1 (doesn't work)
```

So I added the annotation Route in the get method but it doesn't work

```
[RoutePrefix("products")]
public class ProductsController : ApiController
{

    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<IProduct> GetProducts()
    {
        return db.GetProducts();
    }

    //[Route("products/{productID}")] Tried. Doesn't work
    //[Route("{productID:int}")] Tried. Doesn't work
    [HttpGet]
    public IProduct GetProduct(int productID)
    {
        return db.GetProduct(productID);
    }
}
```

The only way to make it work is typing the address like this     `http://<host>/api/products?productID=1`, but I'd really want to access with this url `http://<host>/api/products/1`.

I can add new routes in the http configuration but cannot modify the existing ones. And I don't want to affect existing controllers.

How can I solve this, please?

Answer (score 2):

First ensure that attribute routing is enabled before convention-based routes.

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
//...convention-based routes.
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("Default", "api/{controller}");
//...other code removed for brevity
```

Next you want to update the attribute routes.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/products")]
public class ProductsController : ApiController {
    //GET api/products
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    public IQueryable<IProduct> GetProducts() {
        return db.GetProducts();
    }    

    //GET api/products/1
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{productID:int}")]
    public IProduct GetProduct(int productID) {
        return db.GetProduct(productID);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I applied the MapHttpAttributRoutes(). Then I added the annotations. I can only request GetProducts, but I cannot still get the api/products/1. Message I get: "{"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://<host>/api/products/1'.","MessageDetail":"No action was found on the controller 'Products' that matches the request."}"

Comment: @MaximusDecimus, Did you add it before convention-based routes like was suggested in answer?

Comment: Yes I did same as answer

Comment: @MaximusDecimus, Then you are going to have to show more of how you configured the application. Something not displayed in the question is causing the issue. provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the issue.